# NSOpenPanel unable to select files, why?

Tags: python, cocoa, pyobjc

Being very new to objective-c, MacOS, and not having programmed for years I hope this is not too obvious and thus a waste of anyone's time:

I would like to open a dialog and get the file location back as a references. From what I can tell this should be doable from within my window controller, no?  Using XCode I've plumbed to the openDocument action, with an associated function like this:

```
class MyWindowController(NSWindowController):
    @objc.IBAction
    def openDocument_(self, sender):
        dialog = NSOpenDialog.openPanel()
        dialog.setCanChooseFile_(True)
        dialog.setCanChooseDirectories_(False)
        results = dialog.openModal()
        # test the results and do something
```

The problem is that while the dialog opens right up and lets me browse around it cannot actually ever select any files. What gives?

TIA for any assistance, even if it's to tell me I missed something in the manual (just point it out please!).

Comment: What is `NSOpenDialog` ? Shouldn't it be `NSOpenPanel` ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which files can be opened (using the `setAllowedFileTypes_` method), or by telling the panel that all files can be selected with `dialog.setAllowsOtherFileTypes_(True)`